# Clear SharePoint filter after entering folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, library

This is my first time posting, so I'll do my best. I have reviewed similar problems, but can't find any answers that solve the issue. I have a document library that has metadata columns, that when filtered produces the correct list of folders. However, when clicking into the folders, it shows no contents because the filters remain. I've tried the "in top level folder" option in the library settings, but that doesn't change anything. Any idea how to clear the filter automatically once entering a folder?

Here are the steps:

***Click the column header and select filter by***

[image: Click the column header and select filter by]

***Select the filter***

[image: Select the filter]

***The filtered folders***

[image: The filtered folders]

***Clicking into the folder shows no contents***

[image: Clicking into the folder shows no contents]

***Manually clear filter***

[image: Manually clear filter]

***Contents are viewable***

[image: Contents are viewable]

Comment: I don't think you will be able to auto-clear the filters applied at view level. You will have to manually clear the filters after entering into the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap, when you use the filter function, it works for the whole view, no matter what level folder you have open. and I have researched the conditions of filter and there is no implementation that would fit your situation. As Sanap said, You will have to manually clear the filters after entering into the folder.The good thing is, clicking on an "x" isn't a big hassle. If you mind this very much, You can raise a [uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/) here.

[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.